How to make a gradient an object style (for images)
I have a slightly transparent gradient, and it is currently a separate frame on top of an image - giving the image a black to full colour gradient effect from left to right.

I want to somehow recreate this effect and make it an object style that can be applied to all images in the document. What is the correct way to do this?
